# how to update primary key in java Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on Mvc architecture,I have pojo object i want change primary key please can you help me
          Primary key is varchar
          Ex:

```
Users users=usersDao.load("mark")
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734461/hibernate-alter-identifier-primary-key

Comment: Something wrong with your database design if you need to change the primary key. Please tell me that you don't use "mark" as primary key. Quick answer : Just do a copy of the record, save it as another record with different id, delete the older record.

Comment: As an afterthough after rambling - Did you mean change the primary key columns or the object's value of the primary key?

Answer (score 15):

You should never change the value of the primary key. The primary key defines the identity of the object. Hibernate or any other JPA implementation cannot identify the object as the same object if the primary key has been changed. If the primary key is subject to change, you should either choose another primary key or generate a surrogate key.

The workaround is to

1. Delete the existing object
2. Persist the object again with a different primary key value.

Comment: +1 and I agree with this approach. It seems that the poster put name of a person as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

as still as I understand you need to try SQL/JDBC directly. And then somehow try to invalidate the entity from hibernate inner state and all caches.