# How to update primary key of parent table that will automatically update child table foreign key in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my project I have two tables:

1)BankUser
2)BankAccount

BankUser has a @OneToMany relationship to BankAccount. I give cascade = cascadeType.ALL to BankUser like:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="bankUser" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)          
    public Collection<BankAccount> getBankAccount() {
        return bankAccount;
    }
```

So I want update primary key of table BankUser and hibernate will update automatically foreign key of a BankAccount table.The primary key of table BankUser is foreign key of a BankAccount table. So, I want to update both pk as well as fk.

I tried in two way:

1) SQLQuery :

```
 SQLQuery sql = sf.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("update Bank_User b set b.user_id = 456 where b.user_id = 3");
 int id = sql.executeUpdate();
```

2) Retrive Object n update:

```
BankUser b = (BankUser) sf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select b from 
BankUser b where b.id = 3").uniqueResult();
b.setId(456);
b.setUserName("cascade_new");
sf.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(b);
```

It giving exception like:

```
 (SqlExceptionHelper.java:logExceptions:144) Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myproject`.`bank_account`, CONSTRAINT `FK39272A436B2B33` FOREIGN KEY (`BankUser_Id`) REFERENCES `bank_user` (`User_Id`))
Unknown Exception Occured: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myproject`.`bank_account`, CONSTRAINT `FK39272A436B2B33` FOREIGN KEY (`BankUser_Id`) REFERENCES `bank_user` (`User_Id`))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got it.Thanks bro. We are not able to update primary key in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You should never update the primary key of an entity. For more details, please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6952612/2129801).

Comment: ok, but we can update it in MySQL using   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE.

Comment: You are right in case of a relational database. But hibernate should not be treated as a database, it is an OR mapper, based on an object oriented entity model. For example, changing the pk of an entity will render the entityManager/session cache invalid. Features like auto updates at the end of a session will not work anymore if you change the identiy of your entities programmatically.