# JPA Hibernate - changing the primary key of an persisted object

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to change the id of an persisted object .I am using JPA with Hibernate and MySQL.
The error I get when executing my code is :  org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.tutorial.jpa.certification.listing5_18.AA was altered from 2 to 99

I couldn't find an answer to this problem so I would appreciate your help here.The code is:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Tutorial");
    EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();     
    AA aa=em.find(AA.class, 2);

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    aa.setId(99);
    em.merge(aa);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a look into this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734461/hibernate-alter-identifier-primary-key

Comment: Why change the primary key of the object? Also, if you do change the primary key of the object then how is it going to be guaranteed that it is unique?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**You should never modify the primary key of a an entity** - this define the identify of the object and it makes no sense to change it.

If you really do need that - you'd be better of deleting the entity and creating a new one which just copies the old one but with a new primary key. This way, if you have any constraints - such as foreign keys pointing to the old identifier - you'll know about it.

Also check out the ["Identity and Sequencing" section here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Strange_behavior.2C_unique_constraint_violation.).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right-it's not better to modify the PK of an entity.But is it possible to do that  in JPA with Hibernate? (without deleting and creating new entity )

Comment: Not possible in Hibernate no - you'd have to do it in raw SQL.

Comment: You could detach the entity with entityManager.detach(aa);