# Hibernate Get Detached Object in Service, alter the ID and persist again

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have asked [this Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148169/hibernate-alter-the-id-to-null-and-save-again-as-a-new-entry) and its almost same. But im looking for a different approach.

I have Java Spring MVC application. I am trying to do CRUD on one table, say Employee.

I am trying to get object from database using hibernate, do some changes **including altering the ID**, and then save it again. I am doing that in my **Service Layer**

I have the following code in my ServiceImpl

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl extends GenericManagerImpl<Employee, Long> implements EmployeeService {
    @Override
    public void saveOld(Long key) {
        employee = (Employee) employeeDao.get(key);
        employee.setActive(false);
        employee.setEmpKey(null);
        employeeDao.save(employee);
    }
}
```

But I am getting exception.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: identifier of an instance of com.table.model.Employee was altered from 4 to null; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.table.model.Employee was altered from 4 to null
```

From [the Question I told above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148169/hibernate-alter-the-id-to-null-and-save-again-as-a-new-entry), I have the option to use Copy COnstructor, copy all the values except key and in service set other values and save. And it is working.

```
        employee = (Employee) employeeDao.get(key);
        employee = new Employee(employee);
        employee.setActive(false);
        employeeDao.save(employee);
```

I am looking for a different apporach. How can I get the object as a detached one from session, alter the values including ID and then persist again? All should be in Service Layer.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a copy constructor? Or possibley have employee implement `Cloneable`

Comment: @StavSaad I am just looking if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)

org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.copyProperties( dest, source );

do like below

```
    Employee source = (Employee) employeeDao.get(key);
    Employee dest= new Employee();
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.copyProperties( dest, source );
    dest.setId(null);
    dest.setActive(false);
    employeeDao.save(dest);
```